# Symfony session to php session

Tags: session, symfony1, doctrine

I'm using symfony1.4 with doctrine 
I have php file which i displayed inside the iframe. i have a session value inside symfony
using setAttribute i want to use this in my php file inside the iframe. but how do i pass or use the session variable

Answer (score 2):

Symfony's session mechanism is built on top of php's - it hides manipulating the `$_SESSION` superglobal behind the `myUser` clas - meaning that everything you put in the session is also available for another script via the aforementioned superglobal.

In your other script do a `var_dump($_SESSION)` after calling `session_name` with a matching name of symfony's session and `session_start` and you will see where your variables are.

With a quick check of [`sfUser`](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/user/sfUser.class.php#L30)'s source I believe all your attributes will be in the `symfony/user/sfUser/attributes` "namespace" - whatever that means.